# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in main.m after converting to ARC

Tags: cocoa-touch, debugging, automatic-ref-counting

I have a simple UITableView application that I just converted to ARC. The conversion supposedly went fine, and the app launches now, but if I navigate into a DetailView, then try to jump back to the RootView, I get a `BAD_EXC_ACCESS` error in main.m, and a crash. I tried turning on Zombie objects, and that stops the crash, but I also don't get anything in the console telling me what was happening. I turned off ARC, and again, no crash, but also no more info on what was causing it in the first place.

Any ideas on how to debug this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show some code or full project that cause you problem to us?

Comment: @Jojas I have no idea where the problem is coming from. The EXC_BAD_ACCESS is showing up in `main.m`, but I'm not able to get any other info on what's going on. This app has been in the app store for about a year, this problem started when I converted to ARC

Comment: Without any more info, it will be nearly impossible for us to hop you.  However, set an exception breakpoint (as shown in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10770681/937822 and it will show you which portion of your code is causing the problem.

Comment: @lnafziger: Thank you. I was able to use thread backtrace in lldb to get some more info. That helps me narrow it down to the class that is causing the error. Still need to figure out the _actual_ bug, but this is a step in the right direction. If you post an answer, I'll be happy to award you the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BAD_EXC_ACCESS are a little tricky, mainly because they don't show up at the offending line which causes the error.  Using lldb, you can use `thread backtrace` to get an idea of what is causing it.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10770681/937822) contains a great answer with a few ideas on how to troubleshoot similar problems.

Comment: `BAD_EXC_ACCESS` is a signal, not an exception. Signals do not "trickle back"—but they can be handled by signal handlers. There's no way you can set an exception breakpoint to catch signals.

Comment: The exception breakpoint wasn't able to catch anything, but using `thread backtrace` let me at least find the offending class. Thanks again.