# 'Cannot do a comparison query for type: (null)' when setting up UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

My app is crashing in the app delegate.

The error it's throwing is:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:     'Cannot do a comparison query for type: (null)'

My code is below.  I've left the logging statements in so you can see where I've been checking things:

```
self.viewController = [[ParseStarterProjectViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ParseStarterProjectViewController" bundle:nil];
NSLog(@"View controller is %@",self.viewController);
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
NSLog(@"Nav controller is %@",navController);
NSLog(@"Self window is %@",self.window);
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

It's breaking when it tries to run that last line, setting the rootViewController to the navController.

The results from the 3 NSLog lines are as follows:

```
View controller is <ParseStarterProjectViewController: 0x1fda0770>
Nav controller is <UINavigationController: 0x1fda1390>
Self window is <UIWindow: 0x1fd97c90; frame = (0 0; 320 480); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x1fd97d90>>
```

It doesn't look like anything is null to me, which is why I'm extremely confused.

Comment: Are you not getting more details from a stack trace when your app crashes? Are you using some library that does any sort of query? What processing are you doing in the view controller?

Comment: You should post an answer if you solved this. It will likely help someone else in the future. Edit: Your comment disappeared while I was replying.

Comment: I'm having the same crash and it's pretty difficult to solve as of now.

Answer (score 28):

I just ran into this and it was due to the fact that I was doing an `equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]` in a PFQuery but there was no logged-in user at that point.

Comment: I don't see any [PFUser currentUser] getting called before this crash happens z8000 any other idea why it may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

This really wound up being a question about "how do I get more information out of a crash log".  rmaddy's comment pointed me in the right direciton.

Sean's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770648/objective-c-stack-trace) sorted me out.