# IOS/Objective-C: Trace precise place of exception

Tags: ios, exception

I am getting an exception when I load a view controller.  The error message suggests the program is trying to send length to NSNull as follows:

```
[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b1cda70
(lldb)
```

The last log statement prior to the exception is at the end of a method and from what I can tell although a value is null that it returns, this method is not the issue.

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSLog(@"in titleforrow"); 
    NSLog(@"about to return firsts[row]%@",firsts[row]);//this is null
    return firsts[row];
}
```

This suggests the problem is in some other method.  So I have put log statements before every use of length in the view controller class (all of which are in a save method that should not be called on loading) and, in fact, none of these log statements appear in the log suggesting that length is never sent.

Nonetheless, the program is throwing the exception.  I tried adding an exception breakpoint as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770648/objective-c-stack-trace)

While it lets me view the threads, I still can't figure out what is throwing the exception.

Would appreciate any suggestions on where to go from here.

Comment: can you provide us more details to find the bug. post the code where the exception breakpoint finally ends

Comment: I don't fully understand traces but on the main thread,  it says what I stated above: [NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b1cda70, while in the left pane it says, argc=(int) 1. Clicking on other threads shows a spinning wheel that never ends,

Comment: I was able to fix this with accepted answer from this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607960/nsnull-length-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-json-objects/16610117#16610117