# dynamic cell dequeue crashes app

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I attempt to dequeue a dynamic cell in my table view, it crashes the app and gives me the following error: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]. I've checked my identifier and made sure all the fields in interface builder are without error.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ForceTouchRatingCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

I've put in breakpoints and am positive it's crashing at that point in the code. I've looked at multiple topics on Stack and around the web and a lot of them are suggesting to register the cell. To my knowledge, if the cell is a dynamic cell, there is no need to explicitly register the cell since that is handled automatically.

Also, the ViewController that the tableview lives on is being instantiated from storyboard and being used as the pop view of force touch. This might or might not be affecting how the ViewController handles its tableview.

edit full error below:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18279edb0 0x181e03f80 0x1826821a0 0x18268dc48 0x1000a6948 0x187dd3a50 0x187a49a84 0x187a85b4c 0x100134fdc 0x100135174 0x187c53030 0x187c53198 0x187c42298 0x187c57c64 0x1879e88c4 0x1878f81e4 0x18528a98c 0x1852855c8 0x185285488 0x185284ab8 0x185284818 0x18527dddc 0x182754728 0x1827524cc 0x1827528fc 0x18267cc50 0x183f64088 0x187966088 0x1002e92f4 0x18221a8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Sounds like it's probably crashing right before (or after) that line - the error indicates it's trying to add a row to the table from an empty array.

Comment: I tried setting a breakpoint on that line of code and when I step over it, it crashes it. So i'm thinking it might be unable to dequeue the cell for some odd reason. The error is indeed pointing at some type of nil object but for the life of me can't figure out where it's all going wrong

Comment: At that line, it's going to instantiate any classes that your cell prototype references. Do you have custom base classes defined for that prototype cell? You really shouldn't be doing any interaction with `objects` (which I assume is your model object) in there, but perhaps you can confirm (a) whether you've got a custom class; and (b) if so, what is it doing.

Comment: @par - No, you don't have to register the class with the table view. If you use cell prototypes, it does that for you. But, yes, if not using cell prototype, then you generally want to register a class or NIB for that identifier (All of this is moot, because if this was the problem, he would have gotten a very different error message.)

Comment: @par I already tried to register it and that just caused all the outlets on the custom tableviewcell class to become nil. I took it out since to the best of my knowledge dynamic prototype cells don't need to be registered

Comment: @Rob It is indeed a custom table cell class. It has some functions to populate its view such as updating labels and views. However, it never reaches that point since the code crashes on dequeue of the cell.

Comment: Re registering class: Yeah, registering a class for a identifier for which you already have a prototype is not correct. Re my question about the class: My point was that if it's really crashing at that line, it's either that you're doing something inside it's `init` methods of one of the base classes or one of the outlets is hooked up incorrectly. Perhaps you can edit question to show us the full error message and the stack trace. We're trying to diagnose this with incomplete information.

Comment: edit to add full error message

Comment: Lol. When I was looking for stack trace, I was hoping for symbolicated rendition (so we can see where it was when it crashed). Obviously, the memory addresses don't help us...

Comment: Yea... just realized how little that information helps. Do you know how I can get the symbolicated rendition of the stack trace?

Comment: You can try adding (a) adding an exception breakpoint; and then (b) using `bt` or `thread backtrace` at the `(lldb)` prompt. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770648/objective-c-stack-trace

Comment: I found out the problem. There was a custom view in the custom cell class that was not initialized properly causing that view to be nil. Working with legacy code written by other people and no documentation on custom classes is just asking for a world of pain. Also Xcode wasn't really specifying the problem because the class in question was written in Obj-C and bridged into a Swift project... fun times

Answer (score 0):

Problem was a custom view in the custom cell that was not initialized properly.